# Is $X = (0,1)$ open in $Y = [0,2] \subset \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

Say $Y = [0,2] \subset \mathbb{R}$ and that $Y$ has a subspace topology - the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ - it inherits from $\mathbb{R}$.

I'm trying to figure out if $X = (0,1)$ is open in $Y$ or $\mathbb{R}$

A subspace topology is defined as $\mathcal{T}_S = \lbrace S \cap U \mid U \in \mathcal{T} \rbrace.$

In the standard topology, open sets are the unions of open intervals. [In other words, singleton elements are closed sets].

Based on common information about the subspace topology, I would say that $X$ is only open in $Y$ or $\mathbb{R}$ if its intersection with them is an open set in $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T})$.

My struggle is figuring out what "open" looks like. For example, I see parenthesis for $X$, so most likely it is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$, but this is notational.

I must be missing some theorem or key idea, because it feels like I need to know that $X$ - or any other set like it - is open in either $Y$ or $\mathbb{R}$ to tell if it is open in the other.

For example, the open sets of $Y$ are of the form $[0,2]\cap U$
where $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The answer to your title question is yes: $(0,1)$ is open in $ [0,2] $ and in $\mathbb{R}$. By contrast $[0,1)$ is open in $ [0,2] $ but not in $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is open in both.  That it is open in $\mathbb{R}$ is clear from the definition of the topology on $\mathbb{R}$.  It is also open in $Y$ because you can write it as
$$
X = Y \cap (0,1)
$$
and $(0,1)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.  This is the *definition* of the subspace topology on $Y$.  You don't need anything more than this.

To make sure your head is clear, show that $[0,1)$ is open in $Y$, but not in $\mathbb{R}$.

**Note:** this statement "I would say that $X$ is only open in $Y$ or $\mathbb{R}$ if its intersection with them is an open set in $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T})$" is really false.  $X$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ if it meets your definition of the topology on $\mathbb{R}$, period.  $X$ is open in $Y$ if and only if $X = Y \cap \mathcal{O}$ for some open set $\mathcal{O}$ in $\mathbb{R}$.  Note that by no means must $Y \cap \mathcal{O}$ be again open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: By a similar line of thought as the example you suggested, $(1,2]$ would also be open in $Y$. $X = Y \cap (1,2] = [0,1]$. The complement is closed, so the given set $(1,2]$ is open. We have that $(1,2]$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$ because the complement is $(-\infty, 1]\cup (2, \infty)$

Comment: This is incorrect.  You are using $(1,2]$ as an open set in $\mathbb{R}$:  it is not.